# Connect Dots in the Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting the points in a Matlab plot. I would like to connect the dots as I plot the points. I am not sure how to do it. Here is the code snippet used :

```
for index=2:length(x1(1:100))
    hold on;
    plot(x1(index), x2(index), 'r*', 'markers',3);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered plotting the last point and the line to the previous one:

```
for index=2:length(x1(1:100))
    hold on;
    plot(x1(index + (-1:0) ), x2(index + (-1:0) ), '-*r', 'markers',3);
end
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried, Thanks a lot. I had not tried before. It works now

Comment: If the answer helped you @Kiran (it looks like it did) do not forget to accept it by clicking the green checkmark beside it. Thanks!